# Laravel 5.6.27 - How can I make custom Form Macros?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5, macros

First of all, I'm very new to [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6).

At the moment, I'm trying to make custom [Macros](https://tighten.co/blog/the-magic-of-laravel-macros) for `forms` in [Laravel 5.6.27](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6)

This is what I have:

***app/Services/Macros.php***

```
<?php namespace App\Services;

use Collective\Html\FormBuilder;

class Macros extends FormBuilder {
  public function selectState($name, $selected = null, $options = array())
  {
    $list = [
      '' => 'Select One...',
      'AL' => 'Alabama',
      'AK' => 'Alaska',
      'AZ' => 'Arizona',
      'AR' => 'Arkansas',
      'CA' => 'California',
      'CO' => 'Colorado',
      'CT' => 'Connecticut',
      'DE' => 'Delaware',
      'DC' => 'District of Columbia',
      'FL' => 'Florida',
      'GA' => 'Georgia',
      'HI' => 'Hawaii',
      'ID' => 'Idaho',
      'IL' => 'Illinois',
      'IN' => 'Indiana',
      'IA' => 'Iowa',
      'KS' => 'Kansas',
      'KY' => 'Kentucky',
      'LA' => 'Louisiana',
      'ME' => 'Maine',
      'MD' => 'Maryland',
      'MA' => 'Massachusetts',
      'MI' => 'Michigan',
      'MN' => 'Minnesota',
      'MS' => 'Mississippi',
      'MO' => 'Missouri',
      'MT' => 'Montana',
      'NE' => 'Nebraska',
      'NV' => 'Nevada',
      'NH' => 'New Hampshire',
      'NJ' => 'New Jersey',
      'NM' => 'New Mexico',
      'NY' => 'New York',
      'NC' => 'North Carolina',
      'ND' => 'North Dakota',
      'OH' => 'Ohio',
      'OK' => 'Oklahoma',
      'OR' => 'Oregon',
      'PA' => 'Pennsylvania',
      'RI' => 'Rhode Island',
      'SC' => 'South Carolina',
      'SD' => 'South Dakota',
      'TN' => 'Tennessee',
      'TX' => 'Texas',
      'UT' => 'Utah',
      'VT' => 'Vermont',
      'VA' => 'Virginia',
      'WA' => 'Washington',
      'WV' => 'West Virginia',
      'WI' => 'Wisconsin',
      'WY' => 'Wyoming'
    ];

    return $this->select($name, $list, $selected, $options);
  }
}
```

***app/Providers/MacroServiceProvider.php***

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider;

class MacroServiceProvider extends HtmlServiceProvider {

  public function register()
  {
    parent::register();

    require base_path() . '/app/Services/Macros.php';
  }
}
```

I also added in ***config/app.php***

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\MacroServiceProvider::class,
```

Then, in my ***view*** I put out this code:

```
{{ Form::selectState() }}
```

I get the following error:

> "Method selectState does not exist. (View: C:\MAMP\htdocs\crafto\resources\views\contact.blade.php)"

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Seems like I can't find the `selectState` function that I have made. I had tried a lot of things, but I don't have a lot of knowledge about [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6). Banging my head at the wall over it.

Can someone explain to me how `Macros` work, and in specific the `Form Macros`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't override the library class. You will have a very hard time getting that to work.

`FormBuilder` uses the [`Macroable`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5cac3d475b9b20920ac9b6a20ced14b8ad9d8312/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php) trait so to define macros you can do:

*app/Providers/MacroServiceProvider.php*

```
public function register()
{
   parent::register();
   FormBuilder::macro('selectState', function ($name, $selected = null, $options = array())
  {
    $list = [
      '' => 'Select One...',
      'AL' => 'Alabama',
      'AK' => 'Alaska',
      'AZ' => 'Arizona',
      'AR' => 'Arkansas',
      'CA' => 'California',
      'CO' => 'Colorado',
      'CT' => 'Connecticut',
      'DE' => 'Delaware',
      'DC' => 'District of Columbia',
      'FL' => 'Florida',
      'GA' => 'Georgia',
      'HI' => 'Hawaii',
      'ID' => 'Idaho',
      'IL' => 'Illinois',
      'IN' => 'Indiana',
      'IA' => 'Iowa',
      'KS' => 'Kansas',
      'KY' => 'Kentucky',
      'LA' => 'Louisiana',
      'ME' => 'Maine',
      'MD' => 'Maryland',
      'MA' => 'Massachusetts',
      'MI' => 'Michigan',
      'MN' => 'Minnesota',
      'MS' => 'Mississippi',
      'MO' => 'Missouri',
      'MT' => 'Montana',
      'NE' => 'Nebraska',
      'NV' => 'Nevada',
      'NH' => 'New Hampshire',
      'NJ' => 'New Jersey',
      'NM' => 'New Mexico',
      'NY' => 'New York',
      'NC' => 'North Carolina',
      'ND' => 'North Dakota',
      'OH' => 'Ohio',
      'OK' => 'Oklahoma',
      'OR' => 'Oregon',
      'PA' => 'Pennsylvania',
      'RI' => 'Rhode Island',
      'SC' => 'South Carolina',
      'SD' => 'South Dakota',
      'TN' => 'Tennessee',
      'TX' => 'Texas',
      'UT' => 'Utah',
      'VT' => 'Vermont',
      'VA' => 'Virginia',
      'WA' => 'Washington',
      'WV' => 'West Virginia',
      'WI' => 'Wisconsin',
      'WY' => 'Wyoming'
    ];

    return $this->select($name, $list, $selected, $options);
  });
```

What the `Macroable` trait does is essentially just hold an array of extra functions (macros) and call them via the `__call` or `__callStatic` magic method.

Of course this only works for methods not already defined on the base class